# How may I implement the remember me feature with jHipster

Tags: jhipster, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I'm using jHipster with OAuth2 for authentication, now I would like to add remember me feature to the login form, how can I do that on my project

Comment: JHipster doesn't support the remember-me feature for OAuth2, as I thought this wasn't possible - if you do find a solution please contribute back to the project

Comment: possibly OAuth's "refresh token" flow is a way to go here